# A couple of questions regarding algebraic sets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have two questions regarding algebraic sets. Let $k$ be a field.

1. Given a finite set of points $S\subset k^n$, can we always find a set of polynomials $T\subset k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ such that $Z(T)=S$?
2. Let $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ be a point in $k^n$. We know that $Z(z_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ is $a$. However, is $I(a)=(z_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\dots,x_n-a_n)$? Or can it contain some other element outside of $(z_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\dots,x_n-a_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

An affirmative answer to (1) follows from the fact that algebraic sets are the closed sets of the [Zariski topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) on $k^n$. In any topological space, a finite union of closed sets is closed. Since points are Zariski closed in $k^n$, any finite set in $k^n$ is a Zariski closed set. This means that it is of the form $Z(T)$ for some $T \subset k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

For (2), recall that the ideal $I(a)$ is defined as the set of a polynomials which vanish at the point $a$. It's easy to see that $f(a)=0$ implies that  $f$ can be written as a polynomial in $(x_i-a_i)$ with zero constant term (to check this, change coordinates so that $a_i=0$ for all $i$). In particular, $f(a)=0 \implies f \in \langle x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\dots,x_n-a_n \rangle$.

If you haven't already, I'd suggest you learn about Hilbert's [Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz) and understand its proof. This technical result is needed to make more sophisticated statements about the relationship between algebraic sets and their ideals. While the theorem is for $k$ algebraically closed, understanding its proof will help you to become more comfortable with these ideas in general.